# ¿Se usó alguna vez el sistema de "ferias" para los días de la semana?

Tags: historia, nombres-propios, tiempo

Leyendo por ahí he visto que en latín los días de la semana tenían dos variantes, una para los cristianos y otra que venía de más antiguo:

```
 Latín (ptolemaico)      Latín (cristianismo)
 --------------------------------------------
 dies Solis              dies dominica
 dies Lunae              secunda feria
 dies Martis             tertia feria
 dies Mercurii           quarta feria
 dies Jovis              quinta feria
 dies Veneris            sexta feria
 dies Saturni            sabbatum
```

El sistema cristiano lleva en uso en el idioma portugués [desde el siglo VI](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/879/4296), mientras que los españoles usamos nombres derivados del otro sistema (salvo para el sábado y el domingo). Ignoro los motivos religiosos de esto, pero sí que es cierto que si buscamos los nombres de los días de la semana en diccionarios antiguos, nos encontramos con esto por ejemplo en el de Covarrubias (1611):

> LVNES, el dia que se sigue al Domingo, que en el oficio Ecclesiastico, llamamos feria segunda.
>
> MIERCOLES, vno de los dias de la semana [...]. En el Kalendario Romano se llama Feria quarta.
>
> VIERNES, vno de los dias de la semana [...] La Iglesia Catolica le dio nõbre de sexta feria [...].

Hay varios hechos curiosos. En primer lugar el diccionario de Covarrubias no tiene entradas para el martes y el jueves. Y en segundo lugar en cada día definido hace mención por un lado al "oficio eclesiástico", por otro al "calendario romano" y por otro a la "iglesia católica". Pero el caso es que da la sensación de que durante mucho tiempo la Iglesia trató de que los días de la semana fueran denominados usando el sistema de "ferias", aunque se ve que no tuvo mucho éxito aquí en España, como se lee en este texto (adaptado para mejor comprensión) del siglo XIII, que ha de explicar que "segunda feria" se refiere al lunes:

> *Et andava otrossi estonçes el anno de la Encarnaçion del sennor, en mill & cc & xii, en la segunda feria, esto es en el dia del Lunes, xvi dias antes de las calendas de Agosto, esto es xvi dias por andar del mes de Julio.*
>
> Alfonso X, "Estoria de España, II", 1270-1284 (España).

La pregunta es: ¿llegó a usarse de forma consistente el sistema de "ferias" en español para los días de la semana, ya sea tanto en alguna época temporal como en algún ámbito concreto?

Entiendo que en el entorno eclesiástico sí se usa, dada una de las acepciones actuales de la palabra *[feria](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HlfHahn)*:

> 7. f. En el lenguaje eclesiástico, cualquiera de los días de la semana, excepto el sábado y domingo; p. ej., la segunda feria es el lunes; la tercera, el martes, etc.

y dada también la definición que Covarrubias da para *feria*:

> FERIA, dias de feria, o feriados, se dezian los dias de fiesta y de huelga; en los quales no se trabaja [...] La Yglesia Catolica en su Kalendario, contando los dias se la semana, por desechar los nõbres profanos della, de Luna, Marte, Mercurio, Iupiter, Venus, &c. dexando el nombre del Sabado [...]. Nosotros la empeçamos por Domingo, dia del Señor: y los demas dias nombramos segunda feria, tercera feria, quarta, quinta, sexta feria: porque en todos los dias de la semana se haze sacrificio a Dios, y se celebran los oficios diuinos [...].

Claro que Sebastián de Covarrubias era miembro de la Iglesia (fue canónigo de la Catedral de Cuenca) y por tanto defendía esos términos, aunque en la calle se usaran los mismos que ahora. Así que insisto, incluso en este ámbito ¿se usa (o usó) de forma consistente?

Comment: Gracias por aclarar la inquietud de por qué en portugués para los días de la semana usan números y no como en español, inglés y otros idiomas europeos por nombres propios.

Comment: El sábado también es excepción al uso del sistema _planetario_. Del uso litúrgico actual de las _ferias_: se usa más bien el genérico _feria_ y el adj. _ferial_ para referirse a días distintos al domingo, pero para hablar de días específicos se usa el estándar castellano.

Comment: @Rafael cierto, se me había pasado mencionar el sábado como excepción. Corregido ese punto.

Answer (score 4):

Me apuntan a una referencia interesante, aunque algo tardía: el *[Suplemento al Diccionario de Teología del Abate Bergier](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=5dtloetnNSAC&hl=es&pg=PA399#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (1857), que en su artículo "Feria" explica que los días deben denominarse *feria segunda, feria tercera*, etc. por orden del [Papa Silvestre](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silvestre_I) (c270-335), pero que

> El mandamiento del Papa S. Silvestre, tocante al nombre de ferias, no
>   se ha seguido sino en los libros eclesiásticos, y los nombres que los
>   paganos adscribían á los días de la semana, están todavía en uso entre
>   los escritores latinos, escepto en las materias eclesiásticas...

Esta implícita lamentación (que todo el mundo sigue el uso pagano pese a la orden del Papa) parece indicar que lo de "ferias" nunca prendió entre el público.

Comment: Entiendo entonces que los libros escritos dentro del seno de la iglesia sí deberían referirse a los días de la semana como "ferias", al menos durante algún tiempo desde que el Papa Silvestre lo ordenó. Imagino que al final la Iglesia acabó sucumbiendo también a los nombres paganos, estaría bien saber sobre qué siglo sucedió.

Answer (score 3):

El Diccionario etimológico de Corominas recoge, en el artículo **FERIA**:

> En latin clásico feriae se halla solamente en plural y con el significado de ”día festivo”, pero el latín cristiano, desde el S. V, lo empleó en singular para designar cada uno de los dias de la semana
>   ...
>   Hubo algún intento de introducción de este sistema de denominación en España. *Aut.* se refiere a una disposición de San Silvestre, y cita un pasaje de Sigüenza (1600), («repartió el Psalterio por todas las ferias de la semana») ... Quizá se extienda a algún punto del territorio leonés, pero ahí lo típico es *di(a) lunes* ... . Sin embargo, en el Norte leonés y en Galicia ha existido el tipo con *feria* (aunque no tan extendido como en Portugal),
>   por lo menos *sestaferia* (y variantes) como nombre del ”viernes”, desde Santander ... hasta el bable occidental y la zona compostelana